# Please help me with this I want to take date only from varchar column in table of SQL Server in select statement example is

Tags: sql-server

Please help me with this I want take date only from column in table of SQL Server in select statement example is

'By user on 14 August 2014 10:30:58  called no answer client left will call back. '

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help people answer your question, could you perhaps give more details on your database structure? Is this a string value and you want to cut away all but the date? If so, is the string always build up like this?

Answer (score 0):

if always date is between text "on" and "called" you may use this

```
    select cast(substring(@s,PATINDEX('%on%',@s)+2,PATINDEX('%called%',@s)-PATINDEX('%on%',@s)-2) as datetime)
```

replace @s by your column

Comment: No this Given solution not working and also after date text is as per user input ...  thanx for comment

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @YourColumn NVARCHAR(100) = 'By user on 14 July 2014 10:30:58 called no answer client left will call back. '
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@YourColumn, CHARINDEX('On ',@YourColumn)+3,CHARINDEX(':',@YourColumn)+5 - CHARINDEX('On ',@YourColumn)-2) AS Date)
```

Comment: Not working it gives error  Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The substring function requires 3 argument(s).
thnx

Comment: I Edit my answer. Please check again.

Comment: this only really works if the month name is 6 characters... if the month is, say, July, your substring is then too long.

Comment: @AndrewCounts. Thanks for your comment. My answer changed in order to support each month.